# Set multiple dev packager server urls for react-native app with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm wondering if its possible to set multiple dev packager server urls in one react native application.

When i build my app on my macbook and then run the dev-client on my iphone via `expo run:ios` everything works fine. The App boots an loads the bundle from the packager server started on my macbook.

I now want to continue developing on my other computer wihout reinstalling my app to the iphone. There i start the dev packager server aswell with `expo start --dev-client`.
But know when i open my application on my iphone the error "no bundle url present" appears. Event why i try to start it via the expo go app.

Is there something i'm missing or is this not even possible without reinstalling the app every time?